# Unit Test Controller mocking ISession

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mocking, moq, xunit

I want to Unit Test my Controller, but I'm having issues reading values from `HttpContext.Session`.
I want to mock this piece from my Controller: `HttpContext.Session.Get<int>(Foo)`

With [Mock HttpContext for unit testing a .NET core MVC controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400030/mock-httpcontext-for-unit-testing-a-net-core-mvc-controller) and
[How to mock Session Object in asp net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47203333/how-to-mock-session-object-in-asp-net-core/47203926#47203926) I was able to come to the following solution:

My Test:

```
public void GetFoos_AllGood_ReturnList()
{
  //Arrange
  Mock<ISession> sessionMock = new Mock<ISession>();
  var fooSessionValue = new byte[0];

  Web.Controllers.FooController fooController = new Web.Controllers.FooController();
  fooController.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
  fooController.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Foo"] = 0;

  Mock<IServiceCollection> mock = new Mock<IServiceCollection>();
  mock.Object.AddSession(); // Tried this, but failed

  //Setup
  sessionMock.Setup(_ => _.Set("Foo", It.IsAny<byte[]>())).Callback<string, byte[]>((k, v) => fooSessionValue = v);
  sessionMock.Setup(_ => _.TryGetValue("Foo", out fooSessionValue)).Returns(true);
  mockWebDataManager.Setup(b => b.GetFoos(It.IsAny<FooArgs>())).Returns(new FooResult() { Foos = new List<Foo>() });

  //Act
  var result = fooController.GetFoos() as JsonResult;

  //Assert
  Assert.NotNull(result);
  Assert.Equal(200, result.StatusCode);
}
```

My Controller:

```
internal virtual DataArgs CreateArgs()
{
  return new FooArgs
  {
     HttpContext.Session.Get<int>(Foo) // I want to Mock this value    
  };
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetFoos()
{
  FooArgs args = CreateArgs();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If anyone faces the same issue one day, here you go:

```
public void GetFoos_AllGood_ReturnList()
{
  //Arrange
  Mock<ISession> sessionMock = new Mock<ISession>();

  Web.Controllers.FooController fooController = new Web.Controllers.FooController();
  fooController.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
  fooController.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Foo"] = 0; 
  fooController.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session = sessionMock.Object;

  //Act
  var result = fooController.GetFoos() as JsonResult;

  //Assert
  Assert.NotNull(result);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Hypernate for the answer but In my case I had to deal with GetInt32 and SetInt32 extension methods in the unit test. As per the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions/SessionExtensions.cs) below is the implementation

```
public static void SetInt32(this ISession session, string key, int value)
        {
            var bytes = new byte[]
            {
                (byte)(value >> 24),
                (byte)(0xFF & (value >> 16)),
                (byte)(0xFF & (value >> 8)),
                (byte)(0xFF & value)
            };
            session.Set(key, bytes);
        }

public static int? GetInt32(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var data = session.Get(key);
            if (data == null || data.Length < 4)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return data[0] << 24 | data[1] << 16 | data[2] << 8 | data[3];
        }
```

so following what's mentioned by  as answer I had to modify little bit as below to handle it.

```
 Mock<ISession> sessionMock = new Mock<ISession>();
        var key = "FY";
        int fy = 2020;
        var value =  new byte[]
        {
            (byte)(fy >> 24),
            (byte)(0xFF & (fy >> 16)),
            (byte)(0xFF & (fy >> 8)),
            (byte)(0xFF & fy)
        };

  sessionMock.Setup(_ => _.TryGetValue(key, out value)).Returns(true);
```

**I couldn't find this anywhere so sharing here in case it is helpful for someone who are having same issue.**