# I want to write a unit test for response using session

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core

Here is my method that I want to write unit test. But I can not write the test proper way.

```
public void SetResponse(string message, ResponseModel.ResponseType responseType, string area)
    {
        var response = new ResponseModel(message, responseType, area);
        httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Set<ResponseModel>(nameof(_responseModel), response);
    }
```

and it is my test class.Setup all mock and other requirement. Although facing error

```
public class BaseModelTests
{
    private BaseModel _model;
    private AutoMock _autoMock;
    private Mock<ISession> _sessionMock;
    private Mock<ResponseModel> _responseModel;
    private Mock<HttpContext> _httpContextMock;
    private Mock<IHttpContextAccessor> _httpContextAccessorMock;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void ClassOneTimeSetUp()
    {
        _autoMock = AutoMock.GetLoose();
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void ClassOneTimeTearDown()
    {
        _autoMock?.Dispose();
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void TestSetup()
    {
        _sessionMock = _autoMock.Mock<ISession>();
        _responseModel = _autoMock.Mock<ResponseModel>();
        _httpContextMock = _autoMock.Mock<HttpContext>();
        _httpContextAccessorMock = _autoMock.Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        _model = _autoMock.Create<BaseModel>();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        _sessionMock?.Reset();
        _responseModel?.Reset();
        _httpContextMock?.Reset();
        _httpContextAccessorMock.Reset();
    }


    [Test, Category("Unit Test")]
    public void SetResponse_ProvideProperties_SetSession()
    {
        //Arrange
        var message = "Testing";
        var responseType = ResponseModel.ResponseType.Info;
        var area = "panel";
        var response = new ResponseModel(message, responseType, area);
        var str = Convert.ToString(response);

        _httpContextAccessorMock.Setup(x => x.HttpContext).Returns(_httpContextMock.Object).Verifiable();
        _httpContextMock.Setup(x => x.Session).Returns(_sessionMock.Object).Verifiable();
        _sessionMock.Setup(x => x.Set<ResponseModel>(nameof(_responseModel), response)).Verifiable();


        //Act
        _model.SetResponse(message, responseType, area);

        // Assert
        this.ShouldSatisfyAllConditions(
            () => _responseModel.VerifyAll(),
            () => _httpContextAccessorMock.VerifyAll(),
            () => _sessionMock.VerifyAll()
        );
    }
}
```

when I test the run I got the error this line

```
 _sessionMock.Setup(x => x.Set<ResponseModel>(nameof(_responseModel), response)).Verifiable();
```

that error message was when debug test

System.NotSupportedException Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object: x => x.Set("_responseModel", .response)

Comment: You are most likely trying to setup an extension method. Have a look at this answer and see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47203333/how-to-mock-session-object-in-asp-net-core/47203926#47203926

Comment: yes already i follow this process but again got the same error

 _sessionMock.Setup(x => x.Set(nameof(_responseModel), It.IsAny<ResponseModel>()))
                .Callback<string, ResponseModel>((k, v) => response = v ).Verifiable();